# Samba 4.5 - ERROR(ldb): uncaught exception - operations error (password_hash.c:2816)

Tags: linux, centos, samba

I just compiled samba 4.5.4 from source and I'am getting errors during domain provisioning. Before this I tried installing samba from sernet-samba packages, but the provisioning result was the same... I get the following errors during domain provisioning:

```
    [root@amanda bin]# ./samba-tool domain provision --interactive
    Realm: INTRANET.LATTARI.PL
    Domain [INTRANET]:
    Server Role (dc, member, standalone) [dc]:
    DNS backend (SAMBA_INTERNAL, BIND9_FLATFILE, BIND9_DLZ, NONE)    [SAMBA_INTERNAL]:
    DNS forwarder IP address (write 'none' to disable forwarding) [192.168.0.6]:
    Administrator password:
    Retype password:
    Looking up IPv4 addresses
    More than one IPv4 address found. Using 192.168.0.7
    Looking up IPv6 addresses
    No IPv6 address will be assigned
    Setting up secrets.ldb
    Setting up the registry
    Setting up the privileges database
    Setting up idmap db
    Setting up SAM db
    Setting up sam.ldb partitions and settings
    Setting up sam.ldb rootDSE
    Pre-loading the Samba 4 and AD schema
    Adding DomainDN: DC=intranet,DC=lattari,DC=pl
    Adding configuration container
    Setting up sam.ldb schema
    Setting up sam.ldb configuration data
    Setting up display specifiers
    Modifying display specifiers
    Adding users container
    Modifying users container
    Adding computers container
    Modifying computers container
    Setting up sam.ldb data
    Setting up well known security principals
    Setting up sam.ldb users and groups
    ERROR(ldb): uncaught exception - operations error at ../source4/dsdb/samdb/ldb_modules/password_hash.c:2816
      File "/usr/local/samba/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/samba/netcmd/__init__.py", line 176, in _run
return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/samba/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/samba/netcmd/domain.py", line 462, in run
nosync=ldap_backend_nosync, ldap_dryrun_mode=ldap_dryrun_mode)
      File "/usr/local/samba/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 2175, in provision
skip_sysvolacl=skip_sysvolacl)
      File "/usr/local/samba/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 1787, in provision_fill
next_rid=next_rid, dc_rid=dc_rid)
      File "/usr/local/samba/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 1447, in fill_samdb
"KRBTGTPASS_B64": b64encode(krbtgtpass.encode('utf-16-le'))
     File "/usr/local/samba/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/samba/provision/common.py", line 55, in setup_add_ldif
ldb.add_ldif(data, controls)
      File "/usr/local/samba/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/samba/__init__.py", line 225, in add_ldif
self.add(msg, controls)
```

Any ideas? Please help!

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
# rm /etc/krb5.conf
# ln -sf /usr/local/samba/private/krb5.conf /etc/krb5.conf
```

Comment: Worked for me too. I started with a clean, minimal install of centos7. I followed the combined instructions on https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=54059 and https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_AD_on_CentOS7 but I could not get past provisioning until I deleted /etc/krb5.conf. I still have a long way to go, but that block is now past.